# image width to fit browser width

Tags: html, css

I would just like to know how to resize an image width to fit the browser width, The image is basically my header image that i want to fit the screen width.

I would thereafter need to place a div on the image. I have the following at the moment but nothing seems to work.

```
    #container {
            position: relative;
  }
        #divWithin {
           position: relative;
           top: 20%;
           left: 20%; 
           padding: 5px;
           background-color: white;
  }
        #imgWithin{
            width: 100vw; 
            height: 100vh;
            left: 0;
  }

<div id="container">
    <img id="imgWithin" src="~/images/image(2).png" style="height:325px; margin-top: 75px;" />
    <div id="divWithin">Testing</div>
</div>
```

Any help or ideas would be gladly appreciated

What I am trying to achieve is displayed in an image below:

[image: Sample]

With 1 being : The image that I want displayed across the screen width (fit screen width)

and with 2 being : The div that I would want to place upon the image

Comment: have you tried to change  `width: 100vw;` to `width: 100vh;` ?

Comment: @Maielo Hi Sir, does not seem to work

Comment: You want to add a background img to **.container** why don't you use background: url('img-path') ; in css so it will fit the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a image responsive You need to use a class like this:

```
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If you need more details about [responsive images](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp) this link should help https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your css to this:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#imgWithin {
  width: 100%; 
}

#divWithin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%; 
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

This will make the image the full width of the browser window with the text overlaid on top.

You are going to warp the image with a fixed height in your html though. If you provide a link to an image mocking up what you are trying to achieve I might be able to help you further

Comment: Hi Tom, I have tried what you have given me above, and it is not stretching the image to fit full screen width, I have updated my question to show what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `background: url()`?

so new html now is:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="divWithin">Testing</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#container {
    background: url("Your image url") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

learn more about [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) and [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Answer (score 0):

what ever media query you use put every where

```
CSS:-
    .container{
    padding: unset;
    width:auto;
    }
```

i am expecting inside container id is your image this works perfectly fine in every screen if you face any problem ping me

Comment: Hi Sir, I have updated my question based on my requirements with a picture. Can you assist me further please?

Comment: as per details given by you i am assuming you want the lion icon take 100% width for small screen and for large screen you want the browser should display approximately 20 % of the width of the browser then you use media query for different screens

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Thanks for returning to this question, I need the entire image(the pink and grey with the lion icon on it is 1 image) to fit the screen width(100%) and the div container to be positioned where it is in my example image(I used 20% as an example to say where it should sit)

Comment: above code mentioned it will work in all screens if you want to take 100% of the image width